# How insert icon in valueBox (flaxdashboard R)?

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I tried insert icon in my `valueBox`. My code:

```
renderValueBox({
  valueBox(
    value = scales::dollar(predito_rf()),
    icon = "fa-pencil", 
    color = ifelse(predito_rf() < 3000, 'red', 'lightblue')
  )
})
```

But, this doesn't work:

[image]

*** I'm a beginner on flexdashboard.

Comment: fa-pencil is only included in the pro version of fontawesome. Try fa-pencil-alt

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But, `fa-pencil-alt` doesn't work.

Comment: Any other random icon of pencil maybe? Look at the [fontawesome site](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=pencil), try one which is not grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

It only works when you use the complete icon name. In your case: "fas fa-pencil-alt"